# Max vs Count Huge Performance difference on a query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have to similar queries which the only difference is that one is doing a sum of a column and the other is doing a count(distinct) of another column.
The first one runs in seconds (17s) and the other one never stops (1 hour and counting). I've seen the plan for the count query and it has huge costs. I don't understand why.
They are hitting the exact same views.
Why is this happening and what can I do?

The one that is running fine:

```
select  a11.SOURCEPP  SOURCEPP,
    a12.DUMMY  DUMMY,
    a11.SIM_NAME  SIM_NAME,
    a13.THEORETICAL  THEORETICAL,
    sum(a11.REVENUE)  WJXBFS1
from    CLIENT_SOURCE_DATA  a11
    join    DUMMY_V a12
      on    (a11.SOURCEPP = a12.SOURCEPP)
    join    SIM_INFO    a13
      on    (a11.SIM_NAME = a13.SIM_NAME)
where   (a13.THEORETICAL in (0)
 and a11.SIM_NAME in ('ETS40'))
group by    a11.SOURCEPP,
    a12.DUMMY,
    a11.SIM_NAME,
    a13.THEORETICAL
```

---

the one that doesn't run:

```
select  a12.SOURCEPP  SOURCEPP,
    a12.SIM_NAME  SIM_NAME,
    a13.THEORETICAL  THEORETICAL,
    count(distinct a12.CLIENTID)  WJXBFS1
from    CLIENT_SOURCE_DATA  a12
    join    SIM_INFO    a13
      on    (a12.SIM_NAME = a13.SIM_NAME)
where   (a13.THEORETICAL in (0)
 and a12.SIM_NAME in ('ETS40'))
group by    a12.SOURCEPP,
    a12.SIM_NAME,
    a13.THEORETICAL
```

Comment: The queries posted are *not* using the same tables and views.

Comment: Your queries are not the same.  It is quite possible that the `JOIN` to `a12` is removing lots of rows.  If you want to compare performance, do it on queries that are otherwise *identical*.  `COUNT(DISTINCT)` is usually a bit slower than other aggregations, but I wouldn't expect it to be the sole cause of such a large performance difference.

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges. The first query is grouping by 4 columns, while the second one only by 3 columns. These queries are not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DISTINCT` is very slow when there are many DISTINCT values, database needs to SORT/HASH and store all values (or sets) in memory/temporary tablespace. Also it makes parallel execution much more difficult to apply.

If there is a way how to rewrite the query without using `DISTINCT` you should definitely do it.

Answer (score 0):

As answered above, `DISTINCT` has to do a table scan and then hash, aggregate and sort the data into sets. This increases the amount of time it takes across the board (CPU, disk access, and the time it takes to return the data). I would recommend trying a subquery instead if possible. This will limit the aggregation execution to only the data you want to be distinct instead of having the engine perform it on all of the data. [Here's an article](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/use-subqueries-to-count-distinct-50x-faster.html) on how this works in practice, with an example.